# Notification-box attached to element of choice on ajax success

Tags: jquery, plugins, notifications

**Edit: I had a slip of the mind and somehow didn't think of the word "tooltip". Thank you very much to Clayton Leis. Problem solved.**

It feels like this is something I should've come across within 5 minutes of googling, but I've had issues phrasing it in an ambiguous enough way to strike gold. For that reason I'd like to apologize in advance if what I'm looking for exists elsewhere; I've looked but had little success.

I have a text input which, upon hitting enter, launches an ajax-script via jQuery. Now upon the return of that ajax-call, I'd like to have a plugin which would let me have a notification pop up below/above that input with some text in it. I've looked through tons of jQuery notification/alert plugins, but I've only found ones with static predefined locations, none where the notification is attached to an element of your choice.

I'm trying to find something along the likes of (ignore variable names, irrelevant for this post's purpose):

```
...success: function(data)
{
    if (!data.res) {
        $('.tmp_new').pluginname("A page with this name already exists.");
    }
}
```

Resulting in something like this (where tmp_new is a class of the input):

[image]

This got a bit lengthy for such a simple request, but oh well. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think "tooltip" is the keyword you need to search for. Tons of plugins out there. Here is jQuery UI's: http://jqueryui.com/tooltip/

Comment: I.. That's just.. How in the world I missed that word is beyond me. I guess I'll blame the fact that English isn't my native language. That solved it. Thank you.